# Is it normal to hold and pay for two apartments at once when moving?

Tags: rent, real-estate-leasing

Let's say you're moving out of an apartment and your lease is up September 30th. Is it typical to rent an apartment available September 1st (assuming most apartments are available at the beginning of the month)?

This gives you a whole month to move, which seems wasteful to me since you're paying for two apartments during September.  Or is it more typical to move out on the last day of your old lease and move in the first day of your new one?

In this case how is the lease structured?  Do you have to take a hotel for a night and put your stuff in storage for a day?

Comment: It's too bad that move-in/move-out days don't seem to be part of the legal content of a lease (at least typically)... Despite the jargon, it would impart some protection to rentors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual arrangement that I have seen, when moving in the same area, is to overlap the apartments by a few days.  Generally, the first months rent on the new apartment is prorated for the time you actually have possession of it.  So you take possession of the new place on 9/25 and turn over the old place on 9/30.  This has the advantage of making moving a bit less stressful since everything doesn't have to happen all at once (moving, cleaning, etc). If moving more than a day's drive away, it is less of an issue because you will be spending the night in a hotel (or your car) anyway.

Comment: Your welcome. FYI, it is advisable to wait a couple of days to see if you can get some more responses before accepting. Giving others a chance to post an answer might get you some extra good info.

Comment: Oh okay.  I always thought it was best to accept the first good response then reassign the check to subsequent, better answers.  But I can see how that would be a disincentive to others.

Comment: @AlexMA Accepting an answer is basically saying "This answer is sufficient; I don't need any more help."

Comment: This would be nice. Unfortunately landlords have no incentive to do this and the high demand for rentals right now gives them the power to not care about your situation. Though sometimes it can actually be cheaper if you find a place with significantly lower rent that won't be around for long.

Answer (score 5):

When my tenants move out, I usually need to paint re-carpet or do something before the new one moves in. If the new tenant wants to move in a few days before the first, I'll let them do that, gratis, to start on good terms. If the 15th, I'll let the lease run 15th to 14th.

Answer (score 1):

We had a few days overlap when we moved. We got the keys to our new place on the first of the month and handed over to our buyer on the forth. This gave us one day to move our stuff and one day to clean. The buyer of our apartment paid the entire months maintenance and we gave him a piece of furniture he liked as compensation! Normally when people have just bought a new place they are happy and quite flexible as a result.

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be some overlap no matter how carefully you structure things.

My current renters took nearly a month to move in after they signed the lease, so if you can cut it down to a few days you're doing pretty well.

Hotel for a couple of nights isn't that much, or you might be able to work something out at either end.

Comment: The struggle of doing this, isn't the place to sleep it is storing your stuff. If you move out the last day of a month, and move in the next day in an other appartment you need to store your stuff maybe in the car ... And usually you have to paint one of the appartments, so you need at least one or two days extra storage.